# Input fields with incrementing buttons Jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a A plus minus and a input button.
Input starts at 1 and if you click on + button it has to add +1 and if you click - it decreseas 1. Now I have this html div 35x:

35x same div because there are 35 products each product has a +/- button. The crazy thing is if I click + with this code it adds up 35 (counts products), I just want the clicked one to increase with 1. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
            if ( ! String.prototype.getDecimals ) {
                String.prototype.getDecimals = function() {
                    var num = this,
                        match = ('' + num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
                    if ( ! match ) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return Math.max( 0, ( match[1] ? match[1].length : 0 ) - ( match[2] ? +match[2] : 0 ) );
                }
            }
            // Quantity "plus" and "minus" buttons
            $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.plus, .minus', function() {
                var $qty        = $( this ).closest( '.quantity' ).find( '.qty'),
                    currentVal  = parseFloat( $qty.val() ),
                    max         = parseFloat( $qty.attr( 'max' ) ),
                    min         = parseFloat( $qty.attr( 'min' ) ),
                    step        = $qty.attr( 'step' );

                // Format values
                if ( ! currentVal || currentVal === '' || currentVal === 'NaN' ) currentVal = 0;
                if ( max === '' || max === 'NaN' ) max = '';
                if ( min === '' || min === 'NaN' ) min = 0;
                if ( step === 'any' || step === '' || step === undefined || parseFloat( step ) === 'NaN' ) step = 1;

                // Change the value
                if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
                    if ( max && ( currentVal >= max ) ) {
                        $qty.val( max );
                    } else {
                        $qty.val( ( currentVal + parseFloat( step )).toFixed( step.getDecimals() ) );
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( min && ( currentVal <= min ) ) {
                        $qty.val( min );
                    } else if ( currentVal > 0 ) {
                        $qty.val( ( currentVal - parseFloat( step )).toFixed( step.getDecimals() ) );
                    }
                }

                // Trigger change event
                $qty.trigger( 'change' );
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
/**
 * Adjust the quantity input values
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
            '<form class="cart">',
            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            $product->add_to_cart_text(),
            '</form>'
        );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I made your question a snippet and added some html.  It seems to work fine, what's the problem?

Comment: That is very weird.. It still adds up the product count even with the new code.

Comment: but not in the snippet, what else is going on?

Comment: added php code to, that is all it has. Maybe the PHP is the thing that causes?

Comment: can we link to your site?

Comment: https://staging.freshdelivering.nl/product-category/groente/

Comment: I didn't realize this was a wp site.  Your site looks great but I hate working in wp.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have over complicated this. You can achieve what you need by using jQuery's DOM traversal methods to amend the input related to the clicked button:

```js
$('.amend').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.qty').val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) + $(this).data('inc'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" title="Aantal" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" title="Aantal" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" title="Aantal" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
  <button class="amend" type="button" data-inc="1">+</button>
</div>
```